# subprocess.PIPE no me funciona correctamente

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy probando python socket y ahora estoy probando a ejecutar comandos en el PC del cliente el tema es que cuando ejecuto comandos como 'dir' no me da correctamente el output y no se como hacer para que se vea exactamente como se ve en la consola cuando lo ejecuto en mi PC.

Aquí os dejo el código:

```py
cmd=subprocess.Popen('dir',shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
out = cmd.stdout.read() + cmd.stderr.read()
print(out)
```

y me da un resultado raro donde no funciona "\n" ni "\x" y no se como hacer para que vea bien

```
>>>b' El volumen de la unidad C no tiene etiqueta.\r\n El n\xa3mero de serie del volumen es: DE4B-C86A\r\n\r\n Directorio de C:\\Users\\Administrador\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\r\n\r\n01/05/2020  23:19    <DIR>          .\r\n01/05/2020  23:19    <DIR>          ..\r\n23/04/2020  20:28    <DIR>          DLLs\r\n23/04/2020  20:28    <DIR>          Doc\r\n03/05/2020  22:44    <DIR>          include\r\n02/05/2020  13:51    <DIR>          Lib\r\n23/04/2020  20:28    <DIR>          libs\r\n28/03/2018  17:07            30.340 LICENSE.txt\r\n28/03/2018  17:07           392.371 NEWS.txt\r\n28/03/2018  17:04           100.504 python.exe\r\n28/03/2018  17:01            58.520 python3.dll\r\n28/03/2018  17:00         3.610.776 python36.dll\r\n28/03/2018  17:04            98.968 pythonw.exe\r\n03/05/2020  22:44    <DIR>          Scripts\r\n23/04/2020  20:28    <DIR>          tcl\r\n23/04/2020  20:28    <DIR>          Tools\r\n09/06/2016  22:53            87.888 vcruntime140.dll\r\n               7 archivos      4.379.367 bytes\r\n              10 dirs  239.329.681.408 bytes libres\r\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te muestra es una cadena de bytes, que es lo esperado. Por defecto no se  decodifica la salida del subproceso.

Dado que usas Windows y `dir` es un comando de la terminal, la codificación en principio es CP850, simplemente decodifica la salida, bien mediante `bytes.decode`:

```
import subprocess

cmd=subprocess.Popen(
    'dir', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
     stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE
     )
out = cmd.stdout.read() + cmd.stderr.read()
print(out.decode("CP850"))
```

o mediante el propio parámetro `encoding` de `subprocess.Popen`:

```
import subprocess

cmd = subprocess.Popen(
    'dir', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, encoding="CP850"
    )
out = cmd.stdout.read() + cmd.stderr.read()
print(out)
```